# Very frustrating blue bars and sections on Google Chrome, what is this?

Tags: caching, google-chrome, browser

I am having a frustrating issue with Google Chrome for the first time.

I have a site that has started to get pretty heavy with graphics and today I started seeing **blue sections** over certain parts of my page. **See the graphic below.**

I have tried to back out any changes and remove some graphics to lighten the page up but I am still seeing blue bars and sometimes the blue fills the full background.

**I'm using transparent PNGs heavily and am creating a side scroll scene** but haven't had any problems until now. Why does Chrome place these blue bars on my page? Thanks for any help you could offer.

[image]

Comment: Consider posting your HTML and CSS for better answers, as opposed to guesses.

Comment: I can't really post all this code. Have you ever seen this happen before though?

Comment: No, I haven't. And don't post all your code, just trim it down to the minimum code necessary to reproduce the behaviour and post that. And, if possible, [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I can't recreate it in jfiddle or in a demo without posting everything since I believe it is the the weight of all the images and code that are causing these blue bars. I was just wondering if any one has seen this behavior in Chrome since I can't seem to find anything in Google on this.

Answer (score 1):

REMOVE BACKGROUND COLOR FROM YOUR HTML.

eg: `<table style="background-color: rgb(208, 208, 208);" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="960">`

To: `<table style="background-color: transparent;" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="960">`

And Declare Graphics image ONLY!! Not BACKGROUND COLOR

Hope this helps.